# Upload image to the wall with a link using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Is it possible to upload image to user wall or page or group so it open external url when the user click on it?
I found this exmaple in Facebook SDK tutorials by it doesn't take url

```
 private void postPhoto() {
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
    if (canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos) {
        FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilderForPhoto(image).build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
    } else if (hasPublishPermission()) {
        Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), image, new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                showPublishResult(getString(R.string.photo_post), response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
            }
        });
        request.executeAsync();
    } else {
        pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_PHOTO;
    }
}
```

Is there any suggestions
**Thanks**

Comment: As this is impossible to do manually on Facebook, it is highly unlikely it can be done programmatically.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to set a link as a title or a description of the uploaded image?

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: but my last suggestion is possible to do manually on Facebook

Comment: You are not allowed to pre-fill title or description. But yes if the user types it in then it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. Clicking a photo on Facebook will always open that photo's view. You can include an URL in the photo's description but that's about it. Facebook will parse it just fine and wrap it in an anchor tag.